# angular 4 ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNK_ENCODING

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have 2 selects in a product form:

```
<select *ngIf="categories$ | async as categories"
    (change)="categoryChange(category.value)"
    #category="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="product.categoryId"
    name="categoryId"
    id="categories" 
    class="form-control">
```

and

```
<select
    *ngIf="subCategories$ | async as subCategories"
    #subCategory="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="product.subCategoryId"
    name="subCategoryId"
    id="subCategories"
    class="form-control">
```

categoryChange

```
categoryChange(id: number) 
{
    this.subCategories$ = this._subCategoriesService.getSubCategories(id)
}
```

my issue is after update I want to navigate to the same form with `product.id` with these

```
save(product: Product)
{    
    let result$ = (this.productId)
                ? this._productService.update(this.productId, product)
                : this._productService.create(product);

    result$.subscribe(p =>
    {
        this._router.navigate(['/admin/product/', p.id])
    });
}
```

however, I do not understand why I would get an error `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUCKED_ENCODING` when I call `save()` WITHOUT making change to categories. It'll still work and the change is saved, I'm just annoyed at the error and I want to know why. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ran `dotnet watch run` again this morning and it worked. This seems to be a common theme with `dotnet watch run`. Every now and then it'll stuff up and fails to update something. Don't work late ;)